# How to read keygen encryption key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, security

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name="usr_name">
   Encryption: <keygen name="security">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I get access to encryption key on the server side? And, how to check users' digital signature with it?

Comment: Whats the problem with Request.Form["security"] to get the encryption key.

Comment: Thank you. When do I get the key, then how can ensure the safety of using it? Help can not be too detailed about it.